# OAuth2 Resource Controller in external function

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am using [this OAuth2 implementation](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php). When I validate queries in a resource controller, I check via

```
if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
    $server->getResponse()->send();
    die;
}
```

if the `access_token` provided was correct.
Currently this snippet of code is in all of my various `resource.php` files that are accessed via ajax, since I need the `die` to stop the code from going further when the token was not valid.

How can I export all this functionality into an external function/file `validateToken()` and use it in all my `resource.php` files, without losing that what `die` does? Is it sufficient to wrap all my `resource.php` in an `if` statement that has `validateToken()` as condition?

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on what exactly you have in your resources. For instance, your resources are controllers, which are inherited from some BasicController class, and there you have own `onDispatch` implementation. There you can check requests, and access tokens. The pros of this example, that you do not need to add access token verification inside every controller. I'd implement own OAuth service(it's dependable from your project architecture), where wrapped methods will locate. In BaseController, you can use this service for access token verification, and all OAuth logic will be placed in one place(in service I mean).

P.S.: avoid `die` usage. Implement some simple error messaging...